# How to customize view of one cell on a view-based NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, nstableview

I have a calendar control that I've constructed using a view-based `NSTableView`. I would like to be able to have certain cells have a border/highlight to them, like this picture.

[image]

I was thinking that `NSDrawColorTiledRects` might be a useful to do this. But the frame isn't set right yet when `viewForTableColumn` is called. Putting this in `drawRect` for a custom `NSTableViewCell` doesn't work because this is going to be a data-driven render, like something the datasource delegate for the `NSTableView` should be doing.

Ideas?

Comment: This *should* be in drawRect. Just create a property to turn this on or off in the cell.